# Horizontal scroll bar page navigation with vertical scroll bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

So I have about 8 pages, more or less that I want the user to be able to scroll to each one horizontally. However each one of those 8 pages is also pretty long and needs a vertical scroll bar in each page as well. So when the user uses the horizontal scroll bar they should be able to navigate the different pages, but when using the vertical scroll bar they should be able to just scroll up and down on the page that they're viewing.

I looked at at fullpage.js and sly.js and I'm not really sure which one would be the best to achieve this kind of design. Also if anyone has any other suggestions on how to do this that'd be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go for fullpage.js, it doesn't provide any horizontal scroll bar. You can scroll horizontally form one slide to another by using the keyboard arrows or by using any visual element in your site.

fullpage.js provides arrows by default to do so. But you can substitute them for any other element.

Then you can use the option `scrollOverflow:true` to allow the vertical scrolling within the slides.

Comment: Does this work like ajax when going to the different pages. Like does each page load when you go to it or all at once. I have dynamic content on each page.

Comment: You can use any ajax technique for it if you want to, just bare in mind that you can not create the sections or the slides dynamically. And if you add content, make sure you call the fullpage.js method `reBuild` after it.